# Why vscode shows me "undefined reference" when I call funciton around two cpp?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm new to C++, I tried an example in 《C++ Primer Plus》， review 9.6， which is composed of 2 .cpp, without a .h, the TERMINAL says

C:\Users\SPM\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRnfRBS.o:p1.cpp:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `another()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

My question is, is this program correct? Can a .cpp call a function in another .cpp without a .h? Thank you for answering, this question make me pain for a few hours, I really don't know how to slove it.

```
//file1.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void other();
void another();
int x = 10;
int y;
int main()
{
    cout<<x<<endl;
    {
        int x = 4;
        cout<<x<<endl;
        cout<<y<<endl;
    }
    other();
    another();
    return 0;
}

void other()
{
    int y = 1;
    cout<<"Other: "<<x<<", "<<y<<endl;
}
```

```
//file2.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern int x;
namespace
{
    int y = -4;
}

void another()
{
    cout<<"another(): "<<x<<", "<<y<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you might want ot learn about _translation units_. There is no need for a header file if you put that declaration directly into the source file. However, what you are likely missing is that you need to _link_ object files generated for both source files together.

Comment: use a build system like `CMake`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are no problem with your code.
For example, you can successfully build your program via g++ like this

```
g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp
```

So problem is in your build definition.

Comment: Live working demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/FqEVfXUDtv7gDT6z

Comment: How can I fix it then? I copy another code in the textbook, and receive same error, no program using multi .cpp or .h can pass

Comment: @lnshift9xshift0 This problem is not related to code. It's related to linking of object files generated from code. You need to configure your linking properly.